# Contact Custom facet not appearing in ListManager

Tags: rules-engine, contact-facets, list-manager

I've setup and configured a custom facet on the contact but we now want to be able to segment on the fields it contains in the ListManager but they aren't available there. What do I need to do to see them in the ListManager?

If I add these fields to the sitecore_analytics_index, will they automatically appear in the ListManager?

Answer (score 2):

You are halfway there. If you have completed the customization of the Contact Facet, then you need to add Rule Definitions to the Segment Builder in Sitecore.

There are a couple examples in Sitecore for Firstname and Surname that allow you to see how to create a Condition.

Here's how I would do it:

### Add the Custom Contact Facet attribute to the Analytics Index

1. Sitecore Provides a [really good doc](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/contacts/index_custom_contact_facets) for accomplishing this.

### Create a Custom IndexedContact class

1. Create a custom IndexedContact class that inherits from IndexedContact
2. Set the Property decoration attribute IndexField equal to the Index name you gave the facet in the above step.
3. Add additional custom facet properties here as needed.

   ```
   namespace CustomNameSpace
   {
     [PredefinedQuery("type", ComparisonType.Equal, "contact")]
     public class CustomIndexedContact : IndexedContact 
     {
       [IndexField("contact.NewFacetNameFromIndex")]
       public string NewPropertyName{ get; set; }
     }
   }
   ```

### Create New Rule Condition Using New IndexedContact

1. Create a new Rule Condition
2. Use the custom IndexedContact you created above.
3. Compile Code

   ```
   using Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.SegmentBuilder;
   using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Models;
   using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Rules.Conditions;
   using System;
   using System.Linq.Expressions;

   namespace CustomNameSpace
   {
     public class NewPropertyNameCondition<T> : TypedQueryableStringOperatorCondition<T, CustomIndexedContact> where T : VisitorRuleContext<CustomIndexedContact>
     {
       protected override Expression<Func<CustomIndexedContact, bool>> GetResultPredicate(T ruleContext)
       {
         return this.GetCompareExpression((Expression<Func<CustomIndexedContact, string>>) (c => c.NewPropertyName), this.Value);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

### Add the Segment Condition To Sitecore

Here is a screenshot of an example:
[image]

1. Duplicate this item naming it after your custom facet attribute
2. Add a Reference to Sitecore.SegmentBuilder.dll
3. Set the type to the namespace, class, and dll name in the Type field on the item to the Condition that you created above
4. Leave the Text field highlighted the same exchange change the text to represent the custom facet attribute.
5. Save and publish.

Now go back to List Manager and you will find this Segment Rule is now available for your consumption.

Lather rinse repeat for any other custom facet attributes.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this. Working through the steps ... Creating the new rule condition, using Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.SegmentBuilder doesn't appear in using Sitecore.Analytics.Rules for me (v 8.2.170614). What's going on there?

Comment: Ignore that using. Probably typo. I wrote this post from a bit of memory and some cut and paste from dotPeek.  =)

Comment: OK, this is tad embarrassing but having trouble finding the namespace for TypedQueryableStringOperatorCondition in that case ..

Comment: You will need to add a dll to the reference using NuGet. I think its the Sitecore.Analytics.dll

Comment: I've added that reference. TypedQueryableStringOperatorCondition isn't part of Sitecore.Analytics ..

Comment: Got it now. Needed to add reference to Sitecore.SegmentBuilder ! :)

Comment: I will add a clarification!  Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks. Struggling with the indexing of fields. My pipleline that inherits from ContactIndexableLoadFieldsProcessor doesn't seem to be being called despite the pipeline being added to the configuration !!

Comment: Load contacts via List Manager. It is only indexed when contacts are saved.

Comment: Still doesn't appear when I look at the index in Luke. I've created a seperate question for this indexing issue: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/adding-custom-contact-facet-to-sitecore-analytics-index

Comment: In what Sitecore version this works for you? I have done absolutely everything to the letter, verified that my custom fields are being indexed, etc. - yet when I rebuild the repo database, I always get `GenericArguments[0], 'Sitecore.Rules.RuleContext', on 'MyProject.Analytics.Rules.PeerGroupCondition`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.`

Comment: There's a real possibility this question is only valid for Sitecore 8, just based on the answer date. I'm not sure if this applies to Sitecore 9.